# Cookie Safari iOs

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

I'm developing a web site. The first time you go on it, it display an overlay with some informations. After when you navigate from page-to-page, thanks to a cookie, the overlay is not display anymore.

That's working on every desktop browser... but when I'm using safari on my iphone, the overlay is display,and the cookie is create. If I refresh the page my overlay is not display (which means that my cookie is there).

But if I'm going to an other page, then the overlay is display.. looks like the cookie is not available between the different pages..

Does someone know why?

Thanks

Comment: What code do you use to set the cookie?

Comment: You may want to check the domain and path of the cookie. If you have a different domain or path structure for mobile client that could be the issue.

Comment: I used this code : function setCookie(c_name,value){
        var c_value=escape(value);
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

Comment: But I don't know where I specified the path.. I have the same problem with safari on a desktop too..

Comment: Ok, I set the path, now that is working! Thank you.